# Why listView control not showing added items when setting the View property to details?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListViewControl lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListViewControl : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewControl()
            {
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then i drag the control in form1 designer from toolbox and adding items to it:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(mypro[0].Report1);
```

The problem is in the constructor of the Costum listview.
If i'm adding columns to the control it will show the items when adding them.

```
lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnf.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
```

But once i remove the Columns then i don't see any items only the vertical scrollbar  on the right moving up like it's adding items.

Comment: That is how the LV works in Details view - subitems only show for as many columns as there are.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for what i needed:

1. Hiding the column.
2. Empty string for the text and width of the control.

   lvnf.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

   lvnf.Columns.Add("", 984, HorizontalAlignment.Left);